# В чем суть проверки getClass() != o.getClass()?

Tags: java

Доброго времени суток.

Имеется пример реализации метода equals():

```
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
    Vertex vertex = (Vertex) o;
    return Objects.equals(getId(), vertex.getId()) &&
        getState() == vertex.getState() &&
        Objects.equals(getVertices(), vertex.getVertices());
}
```

Возникает вопрос, в чем конкретная суть данной проверки?

```
getClass() != o.getClass()
```

Благодарю.

Comment: Охм... Она означает в точности то, что написано. Равен ли класс текущего объекта классу аргумента. Это, вроде, прямо написано, надо лишь прочитать. В чём суть вопроса?

Comment: Но с какой целью проводить сравнение классов если первое условие, `if (this == o)`, уже не выполнилось?

Comment: Потому что оно проверяет **идентичность** объектов (что это на самом деле один объект), но не их равенство. У нас, вроде, был тут канонический вопрос по разным видам равенства...

Comment: Для ссылочных типов оператор == сравнивает не сами объекты, а то, куда они ссылаются. Два объекта могут быть индентичны, но при этом их ссылки будут ссылаться на разные значения. Если две ссылки ссылаются на один и тот же объект, то тогда дальше проверять ничего и не нужно на эквивалентность объектов

Comment: Да, полностью с этим согласен. Благодарю.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В классе `Object` метод `equals` принимает в качестве аргумента объект типа `Object`. Из за этого приходится при переопределении метода использовать проверку. 
Выражение `getClass() != o.getClass()` именно это и делает, чтобы дальнейшее приведение было корректным: `Vertex vertex = (Vertex) o;`

Comment: Похоже разобрался с данным вопросом. Благодарю.

Comment: Не так. Приведение было бы корректным и для наследников. А тут идеологически проверяется совпадение типа.

Comment: Согласен, несколько странная реализация `equals`, обычно  там проверка на `instanceof`